# When force trailing slash my href is changed

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, href

My .htaccess code is the following:

```
  Options +FollowSymLinks 
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php
```

It works good for me since if i use the www.domain.com/login link, I get back the following www.domain.com/login/ which is good. 
The only problem is, that my href link becomes: www.domain.com/login/login which is very bad. Of course when I click on it I get the 404 error which is normal.

Can anyone help to avoid this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a relative vs absolute path issue. When you get redirected to `/login/`, the base URI becomes `/login/` instead of just `/`. So either make your href an absolute URI or specify a base:

```
<a href="/login/">link</a>
```

or add this to the header of your page:

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: Hi Jon. Shame on me, I should have known this. It works. Thank you!